# SQL why can't I simply select max

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I don't understand why I can't I simply `SELECT MAX(Weight)`.

This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    "ID" varchar(8), 
    "ItemName" varchar(12), 
    "Floor" varchar(11), 
    "Weight" int
);
    
INSERT INTO Table1 ("ID", "ItemName", "Floor", "Weight")
VALUES
    ('6DC85C23', 'Item one', 'first floor', 0),
    ('6DC85C24', 'Item two', 'first floor', 2),
    ('6DC85C25', 'item ten', 'first floor', 3),
    ('B2B4DC7B', 'item another', 'first floor', 0);

SELECT
    tb.Id, tb.ItemName, tb.Floor, MAX(Weight) 
FROM
    Table1 tb
GROUP BY
    tb.Id, tb.ItemName, tb.Floor
```

I need to return only rows that has MAX weight for every Id. It should return just two rows like this:

| Id | ItemName | Floor | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6DC85C25 | item ten | first floor | 3 |
| B2B4DC7B | item another | first floor | 0 |

But it returns this data instead - why? What am I doing wrong it just a simple table! Why max function does not work for me as expected?

| Id | ItemName | Floor | (No column name) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6DC85C23 | Item one | first floor | 0 |
| 6DC85C23 | Item two | first floor | 2 |
| 6DC85C23 | Item ten | first floor | 3 |
| B2B4DC7B | item another | first floor | 0 |

Here is [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e2ee0c2ac0f48147b198e11f20cd1e82)

I also tried this

```
select top 1 with ties
   ID
  ,ItemName
  ,Floor
  ,Weight
from Table1
order by row_number() over (partition by ID order by Weight desc)
```

From this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group), but this does not work, I don't know why.

Comment: Your four rows have 4 distinct IDs. It's not clear why or how you think there should only be 2 rows when you say you want the max for each ID. You need to articulate clearly to us as well as to the database system what rule you use to combine those distinct IDs.

Comment: Yes I have 2 Id for 4 items. But each ID has item with max weight for ex. 6DC85C25 has 3. So I need to select only raws that have max weight for each id

Comment: No, read your own question again. You have 4 IDs present in your sample data. If you consider 6DC85C25 and 6DC85C23, for example, to be equal, please *explain* the rule, because most people would consider them to be different.

Comment: Ooops. Ive prepared sample data  in excel so it incremented ids. Thanx a lot. Now The code Ive taken from another question is working. But why cant i just use MAX(Weight)

Comment: Because the MAX query doesn't do anything to distinguish the `Id` column (by which you wish to partition the data) from the `ItemName` and `Floor` columns (that you in fact want to come from the same row that produced the MAX value, and ignoring for the moment that there might be multiple rows with the MAX value)